# Modulus and argument of complex number

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the modulus and argument of complex number $i^{(\sqrt{i})}$.   I am not able to understand this question. How can we approach this problem when i is in power.

Comment: How much do you know about complex numbers? If $z\in\mathbb C$, do you know how to calculate $e^z$? Or $\log z$? Or $\sqrt{z}$?

Comment: Yes, i know multivalued function

Comment: What might be a sensible way to define $a^z$ for complex numbers $a,z$? Hint: consider manipulating exponentials and logarithms.

Comment: Okay... i will try..Thanks

Comment: Can u please explain a little more.

Comment: is $e^{\sqrt {i}Log i}$ correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT 1:**

$$i=e^{i(\pi/2+2\ell \pi)}$$

**HINT 2:**

$$\sqrt{i}=\pm e^{i\pi/4}=\pm \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)$$

Comment: I am sorry i am still not able to proceed with these hints.

Comment: $$i^{\sqrt{i}}=\left(e^{i(\pi/2+2\ell \pi)}\right)^{\pm \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)}=e^{\pm i(\pi/2+2\ell \pi)\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)}$$

Comment: You're welcome!  It was my pleasure.